# Using materials properly in three.js

Tags: three.js

Right now i am designing a system which allows users to create objects and specify new materials. I've made things so that users create a material, add it to a dictionary of materials, and then when they create objects they choose a material from that dictionary. The "problem" im having is that because the objects reference a material from the dictionary, changes made to those materials change ALL the objects with those materials. I'm not sure if this is "good", my reasoning at the time was that doing things this way is what i had assumed "best practice", since sharing redundant materials SEEMS like it would be easier on the gpu than giving each object its own clone of that material, and then forcing the gpu to change between those materials.

I made this assumption without actually knowing what was going on inside of three.js, so i feel like i've potentially done something which offers absolutely no benefit, AND makes controlling the individual properties of an objects material a pain in the ass (you have to make it its OWN material each time).

What i'd like to know is if I just made a big mistake and should change it all to use "unique" copies of the defined materials in the dictionary, or if the way i have things now is actually optimizing anything.

Comment: It is difficult to advise you without knowing exactly what you are doing and how you are creating your materials. To be effient, you want to reuse shader programs. Type `renderer.info` into the console and experiment. Then if you need to, provide more detail and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will not greatly reduce the performance. Also you may do clone of material from dictionary only if user try to changing them.
I don't remember that Three.js materials strongly influenced by the performance.
Clone method there http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/Material

Comment: Im not 100% on what the clone method is doing though. Does it create a reference or a new material?

Comment: It create new material, look the code [github three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/materials/MeshBasicMaterial.js). I think you need just clone new material, if it _really_ needed, if user try to change material. But if user not changed material, object continuing use material from dictionary.